# How do I download Jupyter on M2 Macbook?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I have tried many tutorials on Youtube and followed many instructions on github, but I keep running into errors when I try to use Jupyter Notebook. People in the replies also face the same issue, but I could not find anyone with a solution. I am trying to run TensorFlow.

Whenever I run Jupyter Notebook and open a new file, this is what it says in terminal:

[image]

Comment: You provided zero information about how you installed jupyter, how can you expect people to help?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yeah my bad... I was able to use Jupyter notebook in vs code...

Comment: Hi @Joseph Choi, It seems you could not setup tensorflow in your system correctly for conda environment. Please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) official link to install tensorflow with Anaconda. Let us know if the issue still persists.